# Не работает Scroll на Win7

Tags: c#, winforms, прокрутка

В общем есть UserControl на нем панел (на панели рисую графику). Дело в том, что на Win7 не работает колесо мыши, даже если кликнуть по контролу, все равно не работает, а на Win10 работает. Есть UserControl со списком UserControl, таже самая проблема. В первом случае скролл включен у UserControl, а размер меняю у панели, соответственно сама полоса прокрутки появляется, за нее можно тянуть (это работает), а вот на колесо не реагирует.

У кого какие мысли? :)

Comment: Мысли выставить минимальную ширину элемента где контрол прокрутки.

Comment: Извиняюсь, выходные. Не совсем понял какую ширину выставить минимальной и какой смысл. Ширина панели у меня равна ширине контейнера, а высоту панели устанавливаю относительно нарисованного контента. Прокрутка та  вертикальная. Не понятна Ваша мысль.

Comment: Вероятно контрол не может высчитать размер поля, по этому не показывает скролл, это типовая причина. Лечится выставлением параметра MinWidth

Comment: Говорю же. Полоса прокрутки есть, за неё можно таскать мышкой и контент прокручивается. Не работает колесо. Кстати вот что вспомнил, есть вариант, на usercontrol сложен список usercontrol (самописный список, ставлю им Dock = top), так вот на контрольчиках на каждом есть текстбокс, если кликнуть на текстбокс, то колесико начинает работать.